# Split using regular expression, but getting first array element as blank space

Tags: java, regex, split

Kidly help me findout why `ac[0]` is blank

```
public class AddtheNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String abc="bajsd 7 jns 87 5";
        String ac[]=abc.trim().split("\\D+");

        System.out.println(ac[0]);
        System.out.println(ac[1]);
        System.out.println(ac[2]);
      }
}
```

Comment: It splits on anything not a digit, the first character is not a digit, so it splits immediately. Please think about what it is that you are doing before posting a question. Get out your rubber ducky next time.

Comment: what about  //String ac[]=abc.trim().split("\\D+");
       String ac[]=abc.trim().split("[a-zA-Z ]+");//space after Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are splitting on not digits, and the first thing is not a digit. Hence the blank. I would try something like this

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class AddtheNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
       Matcher m = p.matcher("bajsd 7 jns 87 5");
       while (m.find()) {
         System.out.println(m.group());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to raise one query

Comment: what is '-?' here

Comment: From the handy Regex Tester at https://regex101.com/ /
-?\\d+
/
g
-? matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\\ matches the character \ literally (case sensitive)
d+ matches the character d literally (case sensitive)
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)